# How to insert hyperlink into access database via sql?

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access, ms-word

I have a fairly simple MS Access Database that contains some metadata about a bunch of documents and a hyperlink field that links to the document on our network drive.

However, when I use a SQL INSERT statement to populate the hyperlink field, the value I give it only becomes the display text, not the actual link.

How can I make the value a functional hyperlink?  I'd think that the hyperlink data type would actually create hyperlinks.

I'm using Access 2002 SP3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not like hyperlink fields they are inconvenient and difficult to edit. It is much easier to use a text or memo field and use followhyperlink in the code for your form. That being said, the format for a hyperlink is:

```
DisplayPart#hyperlinkpart#
```

So

```
StackOverflow#http://stackoverflow.com#
```

Comment: I need the link to be functional in datasheet view.  Otherwise I would just put it in the VBA click event.  The hyperlink formating you listed is correct though.